# How do i use numpy.view with string data in numba

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I can't get the following code to jit using numba. Is there an alternative method? I want the result to be an array of strings. The code runs exactly as expected without the numba jit.

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

@jit(nopython=True)
def test():
    chars = np.array([[97, 98, 99, 0, 0],[99, 98, 97, 0, 0]], dtype=np.uint8)
    return chars.view(dtype='<S5').astype(str).squeeze()

test()
```

Comment: AFAIK this is not supported yet. Strings are barely supported by Numba and there is no plan to support them better any time soon. Even when a string-based code works, it is generally significantly slower than CPython (even basic loops operating on strings are insanely slow)... I advise you to do that in Cython if performance matters (if so, I also advise you not to use unicode strings if possible since they are slow to compute).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked about this on the numba gitter channel was told that this isn't supported. I settled for the following. There is additional processing in the real function which is jittable and pulling out this last small part allowed the speed ups to take place on all the rest to great effect.

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

@jit(nopython=True)
def test():
    chars = np.array([[97, 98, 99, 0, 0],[99, 98, 97, 0, 0]], dtype=np.uint8)
    dtypes5 = np.dtype('<S5')
    return chars.view(dtypes5)

test().astype(str).squeeze()
```